# "each one having/has its own advantages and disadvantages"

Tags: syntax

Consider followings:

> In recent years some new models have been proposed, each one **has** its own advantages and disadvantages.
>
> In recent years some new models have been proposed, each one **having** its own advantages and disadvantages.

I used "has" but my editor changed it to "having". Should really I use "having? Why? Can you explain it from grammar point of view?

Comment: Did you intend to write it as a complete sentence, or as a part of a longer sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you have two sentences:

> *In recent years some new models have been proposed.*
>   *Each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.*

Trying to combine the two into a single sentence with a comma is awkward. It's usually regarded as an error in technical writing. There are several ways to combine the two sentences. Here are some examples:

Using "and":

> *In recent years some new models have been proposed, and each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.*

Using a semicolon:

> *In recent years some new models have been proposed; each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.*

Using a participial clause (which is what your editor chose):

> *In recent years some new models have been proposed, each one **having** its own advantages and disadvantages.*

Turning the second sentence into a participial clause allows the two ideas to stay together in the same sentence because a participial clause functions as an adverb (or an adverbial clause). To be precise, this is called an **[absolute clause](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/absolu-absolute-eng.html)**. Also related: [choster's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17115/3281).

Comment: I'm not a real fan of absolute clauses, so I pushed it too far, I guess. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Good for you! (or Good on you!, I guess, in the Australian ambit). Absolute clauses must be used with great discretion, like habanero peppers. But this is not an absolute clause; it's an ordinary participle clause, having the same subject as its matrix clause.

Comment: Thanks. I also find out this line really informative: http://www.myteacherpages.com/webpages/ewevodau/literary_tools.cfm?subpage=688018

Answer (score 0):

The use of "having" is probably related to the part of the sentence preceding the one stated. It is more a question of wording rather than grammar.