# "any other verbs then being located in VP" -- is this acceptable?

Tags: syntax, absolute-clauses

> if the sentence you are analysing contains a modal verb, then it is positioned in ‘I’,**any other verbs then being located in VP.** 
>     (English Syntax and Argumentation - Bas Aarts)

At first, I think the The bold clause should be "...is located..." but then I realize it might be in the form of a non-finite clause (ing clause with a subject) but I'm not sure. If it isn't, how you describe this usage? Is this common in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause you ask about is indeed a non-finite clause headed by a present participle (*being located*).

A clause of this sort is called an *absolute clause*. Unlike an ordinary *participle clause*, whose subject is inferred to be a constituent of the main clause and which thus is taken to modify that constituent, an absolute clause has its own subject. It has consequently only a very loose connection to the main clause: it is essentially an independent clause which is formally subordinated (by its non-finite verb) to its main clause so that it is cast as a ‘supplement’ to that main clause.

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17115/32) and [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20170/32) have more to say about absolute clauses.

Comment: Thank you Mr StoneyB. Does the word "then" function as a conjunctive adverb ? Can I insert more  adverbs in such clauses.

Comment: @user2747502 1) No, it's an ordinary adverb meaning "next, thereafter". 2) Fersher. "... any other verbs thereupon/subsequently/in due course/in the fullness of time being located in VP.

Comment: "next, thereafter": I think it's a bit more like *in that case*, the same kind of *then* that we find in *if...then...* - But that's just my opinion :) Nice answer +1