# “What do you mean?” I say, my brows furrowing in confusion. - Is this a participial phrase?

Tags: sentence-construction, participle-clauses

I can't understand how the phrase "my brows furrowing in confusion" doesn't have any verb. In the Elements of Style, I read that "A participial phrase at the beginning of a sentence must refer to the grammatical subject." I wonder if the sentence below provides a participial phrase or something else.

> [“What do you mean?” I say, my brows furrowing in confusion.](http://jerz.setonhill.edu/writing/creative1/writing-effective-dialogue/)

Answer (score 2):

That is a participle clause, but it doesn't "attach" to anything because it has its own subject, *my brow*. Such loosely attached clauses are called "absolutes"; see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17110/32) and [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31220/32).